# cannot find connection object in catch block?

Tags: java

I've my connection established like in the following snippet. I am trying to use the same connection again in the `catch` block as shown:

```
Statement InsertRemoteResultsStmt = null;
try {
     Connection connRemote = DriverManager.getConnection("//my urls here");

     // other stuff here
}
catch(SQLException ex)
{
    InsertRemoteResultsStmt = connRemote.createStatement(); // error comes here

}
```

I get an error in Netbeans `"cannot find symbol connRemote"`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to move the declaration `Connection connRemote` outside before the `try {` block starts. Right now the variable `connRemote` is local to the try-block and not visible with in the catch-block.

Comment: Hmm, I was just wondering if that was required to stay inside try so that if something goes wrong in establishing a connection, an exception could be caught?

Comment: The assignment `connRemote = DriverManager.getConnection("//my urls here");`, is still going to be there. I was only talking about the declaration, which should be `Connection connRemote = null;`.

Comment: Just noticed that `connRemote.createStatement();` part in the catch-block. That's a logical issue there. If you reach there that most probably means that `connRemote` is `null`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Role of SQL Exception object in establishing a connection inside a catch block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316275/role-of-sql-exception-object-in-establishing-a-connection-inside-a-catch-block)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to insert records in database in catch block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22361287/trying-to-insert-records-in-database-in-catch-block)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
Connection connRemote = null;
Statement InsertRemoteResultsStmt = null;
try {
    connRemote = DriverManager.getConnection("//my urls here");
    // other stuff here
}
catch(SQLException ex) {
    InsertRemoteResultsStmt = connRemote.createStatement(); // error comes here
}
```

However, you cannot be sure that your connection object is valid within the catch clause. Consider reorganizing your code, for instance by nesting an additional try/catch statement within your try clause.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You mean one try catch block is not enough for determining connection object related issues?

Comment: The problem is that within a catch clause you have no way of knowing which statement caused the caught exception to be thrown, so you cannot make assumptions on what works and what doesn't. Unfortunately JDBC only raises `SQLException`'s, which don't provide usable information on what went wrong.

Comment: Hmm, that's a limitation for error handling I guess.

Comment: In a way, yes. Still, handling databases requires a series of nested contexts: no connection, connection acquired, statement prepared, statement issued, and so on. A degree of try/catch nesting is normal. However if JDBC handled different errors with different exceptions we could save a few try blocks by adding catch clauses to the outer try.

Comment: @NicolaMusatti JDBC has an entire exception hierarchy and those exceptions have an SQL State that should allow you to determine the exact error (assuming the driver sets those values).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You're right. I don't know where I got the idea that this was not the case...

Comment: @NicolaMusatti Older JDBC had less Exceptions, and unfortunately some drivers don't actually use all available subclasses.

Comment: I did meet drivers distributed with some form of obfuscation, so that you get very unhelpful "caused by a.b.c.D" sort of messages.